# What does 膝盖 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, internet-slang

The following is a title of a post over 人民网.

> 15岁女孩出版6万字英文小说！不就**膝盖**吗？拿去！

Source: http://m.jy1377.com/a/100/32674.html

My dictionary (Pleco) only has "knee" as the meaning. The same is true of [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E8%86%9D%E7%9B%96).

But it doesn't make sense to have "knee" there. So what is the meaning in this context?

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's a good one, and I don't like it. And I wouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from a net slang "给你跪下了"(I'm kneeling down to you) or "给跪" for short, to show one's admiration when something is far beyond his ability.

> 你能吃六碗饭？我给你跪下了！
>
> 你微积分考试得了满分？给跪了。

And this has variants like "献上我的膝盖", "给你我的膝盖" or "膝盖给你", where "give you my knees" just means "kneel to you". So basically you can take 膝盖 as a metaphor for admiration, e.g.请收下我的膝盖

Answer (score 2):

This is a net slang, refers to knelt/kowtow, extends to means worship/adore/idolize. e.g.

> 给大神跪了，请收下我的膝盖！

See [请收下我的膝盖什么意思](http://www.549090.com/zclz/10357.html)

Answer (score 1):

A meme derived from 'The Elder Scrolls'. an NPC dialog: I used to be an adventurer like you, then I took an arrow in the knee." (译为：“我以前和你一样也是个冒险家，直到我的膝盖中了一箭。”)